# excel file corrupts while reading and writing in R

Tags: r, excel

I tried to read an excel file with 29 sheets having 28 pivot tables totally.
Using R, I read the file and wrote it with different name alone.
So the expected o/p file should have 28 pivot tables. But while trying to open the o/p file it was corrupted. After repairing, I got only first 9 pivot tables and the remaining tables are not generated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: Is it possible you are reading binary but writing as text, or something similar?

Comment: Dont expect the following to happen: reading a xlsx file to R, manipulating it in R, saving it from R back to xlsx, **having everything working the same as before with all crazy excel features and cond. formatting.**.